# For Ruby on rails what is the relation between java script and controller / view

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

I understand that controller is process and calculate data and pass to view.

But what is the usage of java script in ruby on rails project?

I'm trying to follow this [link to deal with my google map app](http://apneadiving.github.io/) but really have no idea where to put those script and how to make it function.It's like Im holding the key but dont know the way to the door.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what is the usage of java script in ruby on rails project?

*Javascript in rails does the same thing what javascript does in general i.e **to manipulate the DOM (change HTML contents)***

- Change HTML elements
- Delete HTML elements
- Create new HTML elements
- Copy and clone HTML elements
- And much more ...

> have no idea where to put those script and how to make it function

**You need to put your javascript in assets/javascript folder**. If you look at your layout file(assuming application.html.erb), you'll see you have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

*Which basically **loads all your javascript from app/assets/javascript/application.js** so you can either write your js inside that file or you can make a new js file( will recommend you to make a new one) and require that file inside application.js by*

```
//= require file_name
```

or if you have `//= require_tree .` in your application.js *then it'll automatically require all files from app/assets/javascript.* For more details you should check [**`Rails Asset Pipeline`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: I just check there is no <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> in my html file,will this still work?

Comment: @wen nope it won't. You need to link your js in layout. It's just like you create a normal webpage where you link all your css and js files

Comment: @wen if you want to use a single js file in your layout instead of using all of your js files from application.js then you can use `<%= javascript_include_tag "file_name" %>`. For details you need to read the link i posted in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First of the controller has nothing to do with the JavaScript. JavaScript is used to get interactivity into a static website. For example you want to show a something inside a div-tag if you click on a button. JavaScript is your way to go. This is the usage of JavaScript in your rails project.

In your rails application you have a folder app/assets/javascript. Inside this folder you create a new file called "googlemaps.js.coffee" and insert the code from the google maps side into it. Your application.js file takes care that all your other JavaScript files are included in your application.

Comment: so that means put it in app/assets/javascript ,and require it in application.js . do I need to source it in html file again with its location use <script src="URL"> ?

Comment: If you did not change your application.js file you should find something like "//= require_tree ." this in there. This will include all file from the app/assets/javascripts directory automatically. You do not have to your .html.erb pages about the JavaScript file. Rails does all of this in the background for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added this gem in your gem file ? https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails.

If yes then you can add html in your view file. and js in specific controller related js file. (assets/javascript/mycontroller.js) or in application.js file . All other changes clearly mentioned on gem read me.

Comment: If I add in mycontroller.js do I need to source it again in html file?I tried it before but not working.

Comment: No there is no need to source it again in html file. If you have //= require_tree . in your application.js file . It will automatically load in your all the html views.